# Create a SharePoint Survey from an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: sharepoint

I'm an admin, not a programmer. Someone over on serverfault thought i should try this question out here.

Is there a way to import information into a survey from an external datasource? I have a user who has a spreadsheet full of measures (Over 300 of them) who would like to create a few surveys in SharePoint so that he could ask our users to rate some software based on these measures.

Manual data entry of all 300+ measures directly into a survey would take a LOT of time. Is there an easy way to get these measures into a survey?

Answer (score 0):

The survey is simply a SharePoint list with a column for each question - Opening the list in datasheet view may get you what you need.

You can also create a list from a spreadsheet - That won't be a survey, but you should be able to export it as a template, and copy the xml for the columns into another template that is a survey.

Comment: The SharePoint UI doesn't appear to give me an option to open it in datasheet view.  How do I do that?